# WebView with Geolocation and JavaScript enabled gives me blank page

Tags: javascript, android, webview, geolocation

I have a website (http://wrn.erik-edgren.nu/) that get visitors GPS location via HTML5 Geolocation. I'm trying to create a application that goes to that website but I'm just getting a blank page. Why?

```
package com.example.wrn;

import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final Activity activity = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                activity.setTitle("Laddar...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                // Handle the error
            }

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl("http://wrn.erik-edgren.nu/mobile");

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "GPS-mottagaren är aktiverad i din mobil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS-mottagaren är inaktiverad i din mobil. Den måste vara aktiverad. Vill du gå till platsinställningarna och aktivera GPS-mottagaren?")
         .setCancelable(false)
         .setPositiveButton("Ja",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
              }
         });
         alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Nej",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
              }
         });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
    }
}

10-24 14:54:12.113: I/dalvikvm(2031): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 14:54:12.213: I/dalvikvm(2031): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 14:54:12.533: I/dalvikvm(2031): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 14:54:12.593: I/dalvikvm(2031): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 14:54:12.993: I/dalvikvm(2031): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 14:54:13.117: I/dalvikvm(2031): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 14:54:13.463: I/dalvikvm(2031): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 14:54:13.643: I/dalvikvm(2031): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 14:54:13.983: I/dalvikvm(2031): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 14:54:14.023: I/dalvikvm(2031): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 14:54:14.463: I/dalvikvm(2031): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 14:54:14.585: I/dalvikvm(2031): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 14:54:14.983: D/gralloc_goldfish(2031): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-24 14:54:15.003: I/dalvikvm(2031): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 14:54:15.083: I/dalvikvm(2031): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 14:54:22.505: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2031): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27701 of [8609a15dfa], db=/data/data/com.example.wrn/databases/webview.db
10-24 14:54:22.513: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2031): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = os_unix.c: open() at line 27701 - "" errno=2 path=/CachedGeoposition.db, db=/data/data/com.example.wrn/databases/webview.db
```

**EDIT**
This is my current code. I have added `setDatabasePath()` and `onReceivedError()` and even reseted the LogCat for another try with the emulator. Same result as before - blank page.

```
package com.example.wrn;

import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final Activity activity = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);

        /****************************************************/
        // NEW:
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        /****************************************************/

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        /****************************************************/
        // NEW:
        webSettings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/");
        /****************************************************/

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                activity.setTitle("Laddar...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            /****************************************************/
            // NEW:
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }
            /****************************************************/

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl("http://wrn.erik-edgren.nu/mobile");

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "GPS-mottagaren är aktiverad i din mobil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS-mottagaren är inaktiverad i din mobil. Den måste vara aktiverad. Vill du gå till platsinställningarna och aktivera GPS-mottagaren?")
         .setCancelable(false)
         .setPositiveButton("Ja",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
              }
         });
         alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Nej",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
              }
         });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
    }
}

10-24 20:02:15.392: I/dalvikvm(2296): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 20:02:15.502: I/dalvikvm(2296): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 20:02:15.783: I/dalvikvm(2296): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 20:02:15.902: I/dalvikvm(2296): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 20:02:16.282: I/dalvikvm(2296): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 20:02:16.402: I/dalvikvm(2296): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 20:02:16.893: I/dalvikvm(2296): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 20:02:17.193: I/dalvikvm(2296): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 20:02:17.363: I/dalvikvm(2296): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 20:02:17.463: I/dalvikvm(2296): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 20:02:17.695: D/gralloc_goldfish(2296): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-24 20:02:17.854: I/dalvikvm(2296): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 20:02:18.052: I/dalvikvm(2296): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 20:02:24.842: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2296): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27701 of [8609a15dfa], db=/data/data/com.example.wrn/databases/webview.db
10-24 20:02:24.842: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2296): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = os_unix.c: open() at line 27701 - "" errno=2 path=/CachedGeoposition.db, db=/data/data/com.example.wrn/databases/webview.db
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why it's blank, but the error on the last two lines there is obviously a local storage perms issue. Could be unrelated, but I'd try to get rid of the error by commenting out the setDomStorageEnabled to begin with (if you need local storage you may want to set the DB path anyway, to make it persistent, and that may help with perms, see: setDatabasePath()). Also try logging on onReceivedError, that may have something?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my edit for current code and the new LogCat.

Comment: I commented the row for `setDomStorageEnabled` and when the app finished loaded the page (which was blank all the way) I received this error: `10-25 10:58:04.295: E/Web Console(674): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null at http://wrn.erik-edgren.nu/mobile:73`. Line 73 is `pos = new google.maps.LatLng(localStorage.lat, localStorage.lon);`. `localStorage` speaks for itself :) If I remove the comment `//` from `setDomStorageEnabled` the error disappears but the page is still blank.